# Array loses value/returns to null after initialized in for loop

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures, for-loop, null

What I am trying to do is send a message from Client -> Server, then send back to every other client thats connected to the server (multithreaded). Sending from different clients to the server works fine, but when I try to send it back, nothing happens.

Each time someone connects, it creates a new object in my User[] array. With that, I can can trigger the output stream for each user (User has a Stream object in it, which contains both input and output streams, so each time a new User object is created, so is a new stream).

With this, i'm trying to send the message that came in back out to every other User in my user array (that doesnt == null).

The problem is, when I get to the part of sending the message back, all my Users in my User[] array are back at "null".

Server.java:

```
package Main;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool;

import Streams.Stream;

public class Server {
    public static final int maxConnections = 10;

    ServerSocket serverSocket; Socket socket;
    ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool();

    static User[] users = new User[maxConnections];

    public Server() {
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(43594);

            while(Stream.streams < maxConnections) {
                socket = serverSocket.accept();

                for(User user : users) {
                    if(user == null) {
                        user = new User(socket);
                        System.out.println(user +", 1");
                        pool.execute(user);
                        System.out.println("Someone has joined the chat!");
                        break;
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Connection declined. Too many users.");
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }           
        }catch(IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Server();
    }
}
```

User.java:

```
package Main;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;

import Streams.Stream;

public class User implements Runnable {

    Stream stream;


    public User(Socket socket) {
        stream = new Stream(socket);

    }

    public void run() {
        String textInput, textOutput;

        while(stream.exists()) {
            try{
                textInput = (String) stream.recieveData();
                sendGlobalMessage(textInput);

            }catch(IOException  e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch(ClassNotFoundException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        }

        stream.close();
    }

    public void sendMessage(String message) throws IOException {
        stream.sendData(message);
    }
    public void sendGlobalMessage(String message) throws IOException {
        for(User user : Server.users) {
            if(user == null) {
                System.out.println(message);
            }else{
                user.sendMessage(message);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Stream.java:

```
package Streams;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Stream {
    public static int streams = 0;

    Socket socket;

    ObjectInputStream input; ObjectOutputStream output;
    Object data;

    public Stream(Socket userSocket) {
        streams++;
        socket = userSocket;

        try{
            input = new ObjectInputStream(userSocket.getInputStream());
            output = new ObjectOutputStream(userSocket.getOutputStream());
        }catch(IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

    }

    public void sendData(Object data) throws IOException {
        output.writeObject(data);
        output.flush();
    }

    public Object recieveData() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        return data = input.readObject();
    }


    public boolean exists() {
        if(socket.isClosed()) return false; else return true;
    }

    public void close() {
        try {
            input.close();
            output.close();
            socket.close();
        }catch(IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }

}
```

I'm not sure if it has to do with the structure of my server. It looks pretty fine to me, i'm really not sure why it would be doing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `User` reference you have here is a copy of the reference in the array, not the actual reference.

```
for(User user : users) {
     if(user == null) {
          user = new User(socket);
```

It's equivalent to

```
 User user = user[i];
```

Changing the reference `user` doesn't modify the reference `user[i]`.

You need to use an indexed for loop to initialize (or rereference) the elements of the array

```
for (int i = 0; i <users.lenght; i++) {
    if(users[i] == null) {
        users[i] = new User(socket);
    } ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: one last thing, not sure if you know much about sockets, but do i need to create a new socket for each constructor? or is my socket work alright?

Comment: @vince Here, you are giving all your `User` objects the same `Socket` reference. Is that what you want?

Comment: honestly, I've asked about it in another post, but I didnt really get the answer I wanted. I'm not too sure about Sockets, and if *serverSocket.accept();* (in Server.java) somehow creates another socket, which is then sent to the user array. All the code I've seen only had one Socket instance. I was thinking of doing *new User(serverSocket.accept());*, but I'm not entirely sure if that'll cause problems

Comment: @Vince Read the javadoc for that metho [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#accept()).

Answer (score 2):

You can't initialize items in a List or array using the for-each loop. Instead you should use a standard for loop. With a for-each loop, you are assigning your object to a temporary variable, and this will have no effect on the List items themselves.